# Is Visico 4 300 watts compatible with Sony a7II?

Tags: sony

Good day,

May I please ask if the Visico 4 300 watts compatible with my Sony a7II?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to place a compatible transmitter, such as the [Visico VC-801TX](http://www.visico.com/ProductDetail_ProductId129.htm), on your camera's hot shoe. The transmitter would allow you to trigger the flash when your camera's shutter fires, to set manual power, and turn the modeling lamp on and off.

Comment: Thank you for your help Michael. I just want to make sure it will work on my Sony a7II before I purchase Visico 4